# Get the max KeyValuePair on a list<KeyValuePair>

Tags: c#, linq, list, max

I have a `List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>`.
I would like to be able to know the `KeyValuePair<int, string>` who has the max `Key`.

But, I would like to get the value of the key. Not only the key.

I'm able to do this :

```
int myValue  = myListe.Max(t => t.Key);
```

But it returns the key...not the value :(

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at `MaxBy` in the [MoreLINQ library](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) library.

Comment: Do you have duplicate keys? Otherwise using a `SortedDictionary<int, string>` could help.

Comment: Have a look at "Aggregate", like:
myListe.Aggregate((l, r) => l.Value > r.Value ? l : r).Key;

Answer (score 5):

The simplest (but unnecessarily expensive) way would be:

```
var pair = myList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).First();
```

However, it is pretty easy to write a bespoke `MaxBy` extension method that will do the same job without requiring sorting all the other values. Whether this matters depends on the size of the list and your performance requirements.

[The `MoreLINQ` library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) has [a suitable `MaxBy` method](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs), which would allow:

```
var pair = myList.MaxBy(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "unnecessarily expensive"? Expensive in term of amount of code written or performance?

Comment: @codroipo performance; `OrderBy[Descending]` is ultimately a sort operation, and is **relatively** expensive - O(n log(n)) for example - as opposed to O(n) for a single-pass "maxby"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FirstOrDefault` or `First` to select the `KeyValuePair` you need in addition with `Max`.

So you can write your code like this:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "a"));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(5, "b"));
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "c"));

var value = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == list.Max(y => y.Key));
```

Comment: Just have checked the performance of this approach against the solution suggested by @Marc. On 10000 elements this one takes 2.23 sec, while other one takes 0.0055 sec. I was surprised with such a difference.

Comment: @3615 there's no way that 10000 takes 2.23 seconds - I think you're looking at JIT cost or something; I suspect the test is bugged.

Comment: @MarcGravell [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wAIM33) you can see the code I've used.

Comment: @3615 ah, yes, that code is indeed screwy - the answer above is bad; suggestion: `var maxVal = list.Max(x => x.Key); var res = list.Single(p => p.Key == maxVal);` - should be much better! Also: what about duplicates - might want `First` instead of `Single` - basically: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uv8icw

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, another efficient way in this case would be to utilize the [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var item  = myList.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Key < b.Key ? b : a);
```